# Value of optional type 'TimeInterval?' with double type

Tags: swift, date, text, swiftui

Im trying to read from function of timeInterval of double type and print into text(). Im getting this error

"" Value of optional type 'TimeInterval?' (aka 'Optional') must be unwrapped to a value of type 'TimeInterval' (aka 'Double') ""

```
   func showLenghtDate(for lengths: TimeInterval) -> String?{
                        let formatter = DateComponentsFormatter()
                        formatter.allowedUnits =
                        [ .day ]
                        
                         return formatter.string(from: abs(lengths))
                    }

// Using it in text
Text ("The length is \(showLenghtDate(for lengths: TimeInterval))")
```

Comment: What is `TimeInterval` in the last line? It looks like the type not some value. Naming variables lowercase avoids this ambiguity.

Comment: TimeInterval is public typealias TimeInterval = Double

Comment: I know that but the parameter must be a double **value** (like `1000.0`) rather than the **type** `Double`